# JQuery display menu items one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu with two menu items and I want to use JQuery to display sub-menu for each menu item when the user clicks on menu item.

What happens is both submenues are displayed (where class="dropdown-content"). How can I modify my code to just display the submenu that is 
under the menu item clicked. Is there any way to do that without having to specify `id`?

Below is my menu:

```js
    $('.menu-item').on('click', function() { 
     $('.dropdown-content').toggle(); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-mobile">
             <li class="menu-item">
   <img src="images/img1.png"/>
   <a class="hide-on-med-and-down white-text" href='#'><span id="lblLinks">Links</span></a>
                     <ul id="linksdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
   <img src="images/img2.png"/>
   <a class="hide-on-med-and-down white-text" href='#'><span>User</span></a>
                 <ul id="userdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                         <li><a href="profile.html">My Profile</a></li>
                         <li><a href="logout.html">Log Off</a></li>
                     </ul>
             </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Inside the "click" event handler, "this" refers to the clicked element. Knowing this, you can find its ".dropdown-content" sibling (there's probably a better way you should look into, but at the very least you can go to the parent() and then find the child ul).

Comment: check out my answer it just works as you wanted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `children()` function to toggle the children of particular DOM

so use `$(this).children("ul").toggle();` to accomplish what you are looking for

```js
$('.menu-item').on('click', function() { 
     $(this).children("ul").toggle(); 
    });
```

```css
.dropdown-content{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-mobile">
             <li class="menu-item">
   <img src="images/img1.png"/>
   <a class="hide-on-med-and-down white-text" href='#'>
       <span id="lblLinks">Links</span></a>
                     <ul id="linksdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
   <img src="images/img2.png"/>
   <a class="hide-on-med-and-down white-text" href='#'><span>User</span></a>
                 <ul id="userdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                         <li><a href="profile.html">My Profile</a></li>
                         <li><a href="logout.html">Log Off</a></li>
                     </ul>
             </li>
       </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is you should use `this` to identify the li you are cliking, and then use [find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_find.asp) to traverse downwards along descendants of DOM elements.

```js
$('.menu-item').on('click', function() { 
      $(this).find(".dropdown-content").toggle(); 
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav-mobile">
             <li class="menu-item">
   <img src="images/img1.png"/>
   <a class="hide-on-med-and-down white-text" href='#'><span id="lblLinks">Links</span></a>
                     <ul id="linksdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                      <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                 </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
   <img src="images/img2.png"/>
   <a class="hide-on-med-and-down white-text" href='#'><span>User</span></a>
                 <ul id="userdrop" class="dropdown-content">
                         <li><a href="profile.html">My Profile</a></li>
                         <li><a href="logout.html">Log Off</a></li>
                     </ul>
             </li>
            </ul>
```